# Cocoapods error installing libopencv-contrib

Tags: ios, react-native, opencv, cocoapods, opencv3.0

I am using this [opencv3](https://github.com/adamgf/react-native-opencv3-tests) library for react native, but when I try to install IOS dependencies using `pod install` i recieve this error, can someone help me?

```
    [!] Error installing libopencv-contrib
    [!] /usr/bin/unzip /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817/file.zip -d /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817
    
    Archive:  /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817/file.zip
      End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
      a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
      latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
      the last disk(s) of this archive.
    unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817/file.zip or
            /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817/file.zip.zip, and cannot find /var/folders/hj/5y2w85bn64n0t7mmzcc9rtbc0000gn/T/d20200815-25128-1yye817/file.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Answer (score 3):

The following silly fix solved the issue for me:

- run `pod spec edit libopencv-contrib`
- locate the `source` url (a dropbox link)
- replace `?dl=0` with `?dl=1`
- save the file && run `pod install`
  Now the installation should complete without errors.